# Sharing bitmap through intent doesn't clear previous bitmap

Tags: android-intent, bitmap, share

I'm trying to share a bitmap through `intent` by clicking the share button I have made in `activity`. The first time, it shares correctly the bitmap, but if I click my share button again and try to share another bitmap, it shares previous bitmap.

Here qrCodeFrame is my FrameLayout and I am changing layout color dynamically and after chaning i am creating bitmap of this layout and then sharing it via intent.

```
private void share() {

    qrCodeFrame.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    qrCodeFrame.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bitap = qrCodeFrame.getDrawingCache();
    String pathofBmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getActivity().getContentResolver(), bitap, "QR code", "Scan this QR code");
    Uri bmpUri = Uri.parse(pathofBmp);
    final Intent emailIntent1 = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    emailIntent1.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
    emailIntent1.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Any Subject");
    emailIntent1.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, SharedPreference.getFacebookDataObtainedFromServer(getActivity()).getUserName() + " invites you to join.");
    emailIntent1.setType("image/png");
    startActivity(emailIntent1);
}
```

Comment: Could you put some code for us to see ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got my answer.

I was making changes in the layout and sharing the bitmap of that layout through intent. This process i was doing again and again without using following two things.

> qrCodeFrame.invalidate();
>    qrCodeFrame.requestLayout();

so unfortunately i was making the bitmap of previous layout not of refreshed layout.